# How do I disable all Option+Key shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, automator

I've used Automator to write a quick action refreshing current tab in Chrome and I've added `Option+Z` as a global shortcut for it. It works fine, except when the cursor is in a text field, in which case it just types Ω. I never use these odd symbols and I also want to add more `Option+[key]` shortcuts later, so how do I just completely disable the feature that types these esoteric symbols then I press `Option+[key]`?

Comment: **Google Chrome** already has a default _keyboard shortcut_ to reload the current tab: **⌘R**

Comment: I want to reload tab when I'm writing code in an IDE on a different screen

Comment: Apple uses option for special characters.  Can you use control or command intead?

Comment: @TomGewecke A lot of combinations with control or command are used by other apps, so I'd really prefer option instead

Comment: You could try making a custom keyboard layout with Ukelele where you changed all the option layer mappings to the same as the top layer.  But I don't know if shortcuts with that would work or not.